# Change Data Capture is not Deleting Rows Older than the Configured Retention Period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-agent-job, change-data-capture, sql-agent

I enabled change data capture and set the retention to 2 days. I have CU update 31 and above installed. Old CDC records are not deleting.

The SQL Agent cleanup jobs are running successfully.

What should I look at to resolve this? Is there anything else I should be looking at to resolve this?

My DBAs would not be happy if I deploy this to prod in it current state.

I analyzed the code of the SQL agent jobs. It does appear as some stored procedures are missing. However, the jobs run successfully without error.

Comment: What happens if you run `sys.sp_cdc_drop_job` to drop the existing cleanup job and `sys.sp_cdc_add_job` to re-add it? Is it the case that all tables' data is not getting cleaned up? Or only some? If the latter, does that correspond to your observation that "some stored procedures are missing"?

Comment: I just found sp_cdc_change job and set the retention rate to what I set on the DB which is an artificially low 5 minutes. Still no change in CDC record count. I did your drop job and add job suggestion. The retention for the job was back to the default of 4320 minutes.  I again set it to 5 minutes. I ran the job again and still no decrease in CDC records.

Comment: Though I'm not seeing it called out in the documentation, I suspect that 5 minutes is too small and the procedure is silently rejecting your request. And I tend to agree - at some point whatever is reading the CDC data will fail and that 5 minute retention will not be good enough. Try setting it to one day and see if that works. If you need a shorter retention, my suggestion would be to do a binary search for what the smallest value is that works.

Comment: I haven't found the 100% reproducible steps yet. However, after bouts of reconfiguring retention settings, stop the job, deleting the job, adding it back, and/or SQL agent restart, etc. the records started getting purged.

Answer (score 0):

I had "Change Tracking" settings confused with "Change Data Capture" settings. Running this solves retention and purging of old records for CDC.

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_change_job
    @job_type = N'cleanup',
    @retention = 15;
```